# Pass array pointer to C function with struct return type using Python's ctypes

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I have a C function -

```
ERROR foo(int32_t* toptr, int64_t length) { 
    for (int32_t i = 0;  i < length;  i++) { 
        toptr[i] = i; 
    } 
    return bar(); 
}
```

`ERROR`and `bar` are defined as  -

```
#define ERROR struct Error


struct __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Error {
    const char* x;
    int64_t hu;
};

inline struct Error
bar() {
 struct Error bla;
 bla.x = nullptr;
 bla.hu = 0;
 return bla;
};
```

How do I represent this struct using ctypes?
According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663141/4647107, I should redeclare it, but my `struct` has a slightly different format than in that answer.

I can successfully load the function using ctypes -

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> test = ctypes.CDLL("dummy.so")
>>> test.foo
<_FuncPtr object at 0x7f6cec73b7c0>
```

If I assign a placeholder return type to `foo` -

```
test.foo.restype = ctypes.c_bool
```

and then try to use it (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4145859/4647107) -

```
test.foo.argtypes = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int32), ctypes.c_int64
outarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
test.foo((ctypes.c_int32 * len(outarray))(*outarray), len(outarray))
```

I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

Comment: What is the definition of `struct Error`?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yikes, my bad - I have added it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct Error` wasn't provided.  Below is an example of declaring the structure and using it.

test.c:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct Error
{
    const char* x;
    int64_t hu;
} ERROR;

ERROR bar() {
    ERROR bla;
    bla.x = NULL;
    bla.hu = 5;
    return bla;
}

__declspec(dllexport)
ERROR foo(int32_t* toptr, int64_t length) {
    for (int32_t i = 0;  i < length;  i++) {
        toptr[i] = i;
    }
    return bar();
}
```

test.py:

```
from ctypes import *

class Error(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x',c_char_p),
                ('hu',c_int64)]

dll = CDLL('./test')
dll.foo.argtypes = POINTER(c_int32),c_int64
dll.foo.restype = Error

outarray = (c_int32 * 5)()
err = dll.foo(outarray,len(outarray))
print(err.x)
print(err.hu)
print(list(outarray))
```

Output:

```
None
5
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```