# How to create a C struct from Python using ctypes?

Tags: python, c, struct, ctypes, language-interoperability

I have a similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663141/3059024) question. I'm basically trying to create C structs from Python using ctypes.

In C I have:

```
typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point ;

Point* makePoint(int x, int y){
    Point *point = (Point*) malloc(sizeof (Point));
    point->x = x;
    point->y = y;
    return point;
}

void freePoint(Point* point){
    free(point);
}
```

While in Python I have:

```
    class Point(ct.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("x", ct.c_int64),
            ("y", ct.c_int64),
        ]


    lib = ct.CDLL("SRES.dll")

    lib.makePoint.restype = ct.c_void_p

    pptr = lib.makePoint(4, 5)
    print(pptr)

    p = Point.from_address(pptr)
    print(p)
    print(p.x)
    print(p.y)
```

Currently this outputs a bunch of pointers:

```
2365277332448
<__main__.Point object at 0x00000226D2C55340>
21474836484
-8646857406049613808
```

How can I instead make this output return the numbers I put in, i.e.

```
2365277332448
<__main__.Point object at 0x00000226D2C55340>
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `c_int64`.
After changing it to `c_int32`, it works fine.
You may take `c_int64` as `long` from C side.

Additionally, you can do

```
lib.makePoint.restype = ct.POINTER(Point)
p = lib.makePoint(4, 5)
print(p.contents.x)
print(p.contents.y)
```

Comment: I get this:  `AttributeError: 'Point' object has no attribute 'contents'`

Comment: @CiaranWelsh Ah... Then, `p['x']` and `p['y']`. Have you tried them?

Comment: @CiaranWelsh `pptr.contents.x` may work. I think...

Comment: No, I assumed dot notation would work. p['x'] causes `TypeError: 'Point' object is not subscriptable`. Thanks for brainstorming with me though.

Comment: Aaaah the age old classic ctypes problem. Would have taken me ages to figure this out, thanks.

Comment: Best not to rely on c builtin types for word length on the C-side of the equation.  stdint.h has int32_t/int64_t and others for this purpose.

Comment: Also, `ctypes` has `c_int` to parallel C `int`.  Use matching types.